# The Tomcat server deletes the folder when compiling the program

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I use commands to determine where to upload the file

```
String uploadUrl = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/avatar/");
String filePath = uploadUrl + File.separator + avatar.getOriginalFilename();
File dest = new File(filePath);
avatar.transferTo(dest);
```

This sets the path for me

```
D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\ROOT\avatar\Lighthouse.jpg
```

I create an 'avatar' folder to place avatars there, but the problem is that when compiling this program the folder disappears. Yes. I compile the program and at some point the folder is removed from the server.
Here he is located. https://zapodaj.net/02080c2c0f844.png.html
But after each compilation disappears. It does not make sense and I do not know what to do.

Comment: How are you compiling and deploying the webapp?